# Newline in Pygame With Unicode In Input Box

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, textbox, pygame

I am making a simple input box in pygame, where you should be able to type anything, press backspace, and add a newline by pressing enter. I can't seem to make a newline though because I don't know how. I want to be able to add a newline when pressing enter and keep the other text above it.

I have tried using `text = text + "/n"` but that didn't work.

This is my Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

winheight = 600
winwidth = 1200
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
input_box = pygame.Rect(50, 50, winwidth - 100, winheight - 100)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
Text = ''
Writing = True

win = pygame.display.set_mode((winwidth, winheight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Clogging Cuesheet Writer")

while Writing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Writing = False
            break
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                print ("replace this with the command to make Text plus a newline")
            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                Text = Text[:-1]
            else:
                Text += event.unicode

    #clear screen, draw text, draw inputbox, then update
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    txt_surface = font.render(Text, True, blue)
    win.blit(txt_surface, (input_box.x+15, input_box.y+15))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, blue, input_box, 2)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 6):

That's because you have a typo in "/n". What you really want is "\n":

```
if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
    print (text = text + '\n')
```

Comment: This did work for other stuff like printing new lines, but in pygame it didn't for two reasons. One I can't use a print function like that, and two if I just do text = text + '\n' it will just create a square.

Answer (score 1):

As of `pygame-ce` version `2.1.4` [`pygame.Font.render`](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) supports multiline text. So all you have to do is to add a newline to the text string:

```py
import pygame


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1200, 600
FPS = 60

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("Clogging Cuesheet Writer")

input_box = pygame.Rect(50, 50, WIDTH - 100, HEIGHT - 100)
font = pygame.Font(None, 32)
text = ""

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    screen.fill("black")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                text += "\n"  # this is the "command" to add
            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                text = text[:-1]
        elif event.type == pygame.TEXTINPUT:
            text += event.text

    # some modifications to `render`, you need to specify bg colour which can be None
    # that's the default value and then you can specify wraplength
    # more info in docs
    txt_surface = font.render(text, True, "blue", None, input_box.width - 30)
    screen.blit(txt_surface, (input_box.x + 15, input_box.y + 15))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, "blue", input_box, 2)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Also you can use the `TEXTINPUT` event for handling text input, it also has that feature of when you hold the key the event is repeatedly posted after a certain delay.

Additionally to install the latest version of `pygame-ce` simply follow these steps:

1. `pip uninstall pygame` (to avoid conflict, this has to be done only if you have `pygame` installed already)
2. `pip install pygame-ce`
3. Enjoy the new and shiny features

More info about the fork can be found here: [Pygame: Community Edition Announcement](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/1112q10/pygame_community_edition_announcement/)
And the version specific announcement here: [Pygame-ce 2.1.4 release](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/11irmbo/pygamece_214_release/)

Answer (score 0):

ok bro here is my code for displaying a text in a window of dimentions of
width, height

the way i get the new lines is that the ord(event.unicode) is 13

```
offsetX = 0
offsetY = 0
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)

tmp_text = 'hi Qdfhasdj' # here u add the text u need with tmp_text+=event.unicode


line_counter=0
while tmp_text!='':
    line_text = ''
    while tmp_text!='':
        word = tmp_text[0]
        if font.render(line_text+word, True, tmp_currentTextColor, tmp_currentColor).get_rect()[2]>width-20:
            break
        if ord(word) == 13: #for new line because the '\n' not working for some reason
            if len(tmp_text)==1: 
                tmp_text = ''
                break
            tmp_text = tmp_text[1:]    
            break
        line_text=line_text+word
        if len(tmp_text)==1: 
            tmp_text = ''
            break
        tmp_text = tmp_text[1:]
    
    line_text = font.render(line_text, True, tmp_currentTextColor, tmp_currentColor)
    screen.blit(line_text, [offsetX +padding[0]/2,offsetY + padding[1]/2 + 1.5*padding[1]*line_counter])

    line_counter+=1
```